# Getting blank signed request from facebook in ie only

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer

When I deploy my facebook app to a remote dev I seem to get a blank signed request returned but only in IE, any ideas on if this is a known IE bug?

Comment: Are you talking about the signed_request sent as a POST value to your app page? There's no reason I know of that IE should behave any differently in that regard than any other browser. Or are you setting a cookie somewhere that then ends up empty?

Comment: yes this is the post value to my iframe app, works fine when I run the app locally but as soon as I just push to dev site (on remote server) I get a blank returned.

Comment: Do you mean there is a `signed_request` parameter present, but it has no value? How exactly are you reading the value? I'm just confused here because the type of browser should play no part whatsoever in receiving a POST value.

Comment: I agree it is very strange as only does it remotely also so thought maybe a domain based thing, or maybe server issue. it is present but no value

Comment: Just to be clear, if you have a page with `echo $_REQUEST['signed_request'];` (in PHP) on it, it displays nothing when using IE but shows a value when using another browser?

Answer (score 6):

Yup, this happens because of p3p policy and how internet explorer behaves with that.  You can fix it by sending the following header data in your web application.

```
P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR HONK"
```

You can find a detailed post on this in the following URL 
http://hasin.wordpress.com/2011/09/30/story-about-blue-e-iframed-web-application-wastage-of-6-hours-and/

Hope it will help.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with `signed_request`, which is sent as a POST to the iframe and not as a cookie. Also, it's a myth that P3P fixes all cookie issues. Of course the OP's problem might actually be cookie related, but he specifically said "signed request" and that in itself doesn't involve any cookies.